# How to disable an onDestroy method from activity in a specific fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, google-cloud-firestore

I have an activity with multiple fragments. When the user reaches the last fragment and clicks on a button, he gets to the MainActivity via intent. 
This is a multiplayer quiz app and I need to update a "turn" field in the database which decides wether player 1 or 2 has to play. This field currently gets updated when...

... the player finishes his quiz round normally (by clicking the next button on the last fragment)

... the player clicks the back button of the phone during the game (it opens an `AlertDialog`so when the player chooses to go back to the MainActivity this triggers an "update turn field method")

There has to be a third option where the turn field gets updated and this is the scenario: The player starts his turn but closes the app during his turn. This means currently that the "turn" field in my database does not get updated which means in my code that neither of the players can resume the game. I want to avoid this by updating the turn field when the user decides to close the app.

In the fragments there is a `ProgressBar` which is still running when the user accidentally closes the app, I did this in the `onStop`method of the fragment. Because of this I cannot call the `onStop`method in the activity to update the fields in the database, so I am wondering if there is a way to achieve my desired result without calling the onStop method.

Here is my activity where I have currently the method that updates some fields in Firestore inside the onDestroy method:

```
...
// When the user clicks the phones back button during the game an alert window opens to aks if he is sure to exit the game
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog();
    }

public void AlertDialog() {

        yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                closeGame();
                Intent i = new Intent(GameActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        updateGameStatus();
    }

    protected void updateGameStatus() {

collectionRef.document(gameId).collection("Round").document("Round").update("round", roundValue + 1)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                }
                            });

        }
...
```

Is there a good way to achieve my desired result?

Please let me know if you need additional informations.

I very much appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no way to disable the onDestroy on a specific Fragment, I arranged my code logic around the `onDestroy`method of the Activity that holds the Fragments.